# Problem release maven

Tags: svn, maven-2, maven-release-plugin

I have a problem with the release plugin for maven.

I use maven 2.2 and maven-release-plugin 2.1

When I run the next command line, the release plugin create tag in svn but nothing is into the tags.
The command line is:

```
mvn  -DautoVersionSubmodules=true -Dusername=kiva -Dpassword=xxxx --batch-mode release:prepare
```

First strange thing, submodules are not release. Here is the command output:

```
[INFO] personnes-parent .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] personnes-reactor ................................. SUCCESS [25.116s]
[INFO] personnes-dto ..................................... SKIPPED
```

And next, the tag personnes-reactor is create on svn but nothing is inside.

I configure the scm like this:

```
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
    <id>repo</id>
    <url>http://10.211.55.4/svn/personnes/trunk</url>
  </repository>
</distributionManagement>

<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://10.211.55.4/svn/personnes/tags/</connection>
</scm>
```

I don't understand why nothing work with the release.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[distributionManagement](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Distribution_Management) has nothing to do with SCM. Try configuring the your SCM as follows:

```
<scm>
  <connection>scm:svn:http://10.211.55.4/svn/personnes/trunk</connection>
</scm>
```

This is the default SVN layout, `maven-release-plugin` will recognize it and tag accordingly.

Comment: It tried to do this and I got this error:   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.1:prepare (default-cli) on project personnes-reactor: Unable to tag SCM
[ERROR] Provider message:
[ERROR] The svn tag command failed.
[ERROR] Command output:
[ERROR] svn: Path 'http://10.211.55.4/svn/personnes/trunk/personnes-reactor' does not exist in revision 75